# Linear programming Convex Polyhedron

Tags: linear-programming

When we define the contraints for a linear programming problem we get that the domain is a Convex Polyhedron .

But, i think it's possibile to add also an equality contraint, in this way the domain of the linear programming can turn into a line.

Is this possibile ? All the procedures usually used to solve a linear programming are still applicable ?

Comment: A line is a convex polyhedron

Comment: Thanks if you add an answer i vote you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line is a convex polyhedron as well, but not of full dimension (except you have only one variable anyway). Note that you also don't need equality constraints to describe a line in more variables, for example in three variables the constraints $x\le y \le z\le x$ describe a line and if you add $x\ge 0$ you get a ray, which is a polyhedron as well.